# Enforcing a min length in Django password

Tags: django, django-forms

I am currently using `django.contrib.auth.views.password_password_reset_confirm` to change a user's password. This is how my urls look:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
    redirect_if_loggedin(auth_views.password_reset_confirm),
    name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
```

Currently, I am doing it directly into the django trunk -

```
# django.contrib.auth.views
def clean_new_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')
    if password1 and password2:
        if len(password1) < 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Password must be at least 8 chars."))
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))
    return password2
```

Surely there must be a better way.

Comment: Won't `if len(password1) < 7` accept a password of length 7 (which is not at least 8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're modifying the django code? Because that's just can not be the way to do it.

What form do you use? It seems indeed that the built-in [PasswordChangeForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordChangeForm) won't let you set a min_length.

Maybe you could use the [password_change](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) view and set your own password_change_form, which could inherit from the basic PasswordChangeForm to which you could apply additional [cleaning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Comment: Great answer, I have added another answer with the code I eventually wrote http://stackoverflow.com/a/20678355/340128

Answer (score 6):

The code that I eventually wrote after understanding Arthur's accepted answer:

This is the inherited form:

```
class SetPasswordWithMinLengthForm(SetPasswordForm):
    """
    Inherited form that lets a user change set his/her password without
    entering the old password while validating min password length
    """
    def clean_new_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
        if len(password1) < 4:
            raise ValidationError("Password must be at least 4 chars.")
        return password1
```

In the `urls.py` you can instruct the view to use the custom form by specifing `set_password_form`:

```
url(r'^forgot_password/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                                                     'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
                                                     {'set_password_form':SetPasswordWithMinLengthForm}),
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the django-registration plugin, which I've found to be excellent, so my example is based on that.  But you could do a very similar thing without it.

[This post](http://www.marcofucci.com/tumblelog/26/jul/2009/integrating-recaptcha-with-django/) does a good job of walking one through how to override a form (and widget) for django-registration -- in this case for a recaptcha spam-bot blocker.

What you need to do is override the RegistrationForm class (as below) and point your urls.py to use it instead of the default RegistrationForm

```
class MinPasswdLenRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    min_password_length = 8

    def clean_password1(self):
        " Minimum length "
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1', '')
        if len(password1) < self.min_password_length:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password must have at least %i characters" % self.min_password_length)
        else:
            return password1
```

(In a Form class, django will look for functions that start with `clean_` and end with a field name (like `password1`) to execute during form validation.)

The other important bit is to use the form in your urls.py, like so:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from registration.views import register

from myapp.forms import MinPasswdLenRegistrationForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$', register,
        {'form_class': MinPasswdLenRegistrationForm},
        name='registration.views.register'),
    (r'', include('registration.urls')),
)
```

HTH